# Difference between SSH login and git push login (script execution context)

Tags: git, bash, node.js, ssh, debian

I have a server setup where we use git as deployment tool. It checks out single `bash` file in `post-receive` and then executes it.

That `bash` script suppose to stop processes by doing `echo "" > fifo_file`.

This works perfectly when someone is logged in to the server via SSH and manually calls `bash_script.sh`, in this case all processes will be stopped, code deployed and new processes started.

But the exact same sequence executed by `post-receive` does not quite work. The old processes are still alive after restarted and hence they occupy ports needed for newly deployed code to work.

What could be problem there?

Comment: I'd suggest revising the question title, as this is not related to the logins. It is related to the context within which the script is being executed.

Comment: @KevinA.Naudé Right, but isn't that login will define the context? Like interactive/non-interactive login etc. I am not much familiar with this side of *nix platforms, so any hint will be appreciated

Comment: Whether the script is executed under the same account depends on your setup.  The script might be being executed under a shared username for the git server.  Did you test under the same account, or did you perhaps log in to your box with a different (personal/admin) user account? [PS. I'm not an expert in hosting git servers :-)]

Comment: @KevinA.Naudé There are few account involved. Because several users should be able to deploy new code. As in my post - whenever it is done through SSH connection via remote console commands everything is totally fine no matter which account it is, but when git hook executes it, it is not fine. But there should be no difference since git is doing it also via SSH connection. So i am mostly asking here about what am i missing out.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand your config. The post-receive hook should definitely be running under each respective user's account then. Sorry, no explanation for the problem behaviour comes to mind. Hopefully someone will come along and enlighten us.

Answer (score 0):

Your have a script bash_script.sh, which is doing several steps. If triggered by the hook already the first step (stopping processes by writing to a fifo file) seems not to work.

Let us ignore the following steps and concentrate on that first step.

There is a fifo file in the file system.
On the one end there is a process writing at that fifo.
On the other end there is another process reading from that fifo and triggering the shutdown of your processes.

That fifo pretty much completely separates both sides, hence any subtle differences like shell mode or environment variables of the first process are not relevant to the second process.

The only point is, you need to access the right file and you need the permission to write at it.

Some ideas:

- Make sure you access the file by an absolute path (starting with /). Otherwise you might just write to the wrong file. ;)
- Make sure you the fifo has suitable access rights. - But that should already be the case.
- Add a bit of debugging.

  - Is the deployment script triggered at all?
  - Does you hook complain about anything?
  - Add something like `id;pwd;ls -ld $fifo` in the hook.

That should give you a hint what is going on.

Comment: 1 - deployment done not through fifo file. Deployed code is launched using fifo. Since process can be started by one user, but later code can be pushed by another user i need to stop processes and start them again. fifo is for this reason. 2 - all users who can do that are in same primary group and have rw for all files in project. 3 - That would be just silly write to wrong file... So all your assumptions are not correct.

Comment: It is happening exactly the way i described. Same `bash` script does everything (deployment, app restart). But when this script is executed from SSH terminal everything is fine and when it is executed from git hook it does not work. But thanks for trying

Comment: I this case I do not understand. You have a bash script (bash_script.sh), which is executed either by an interactive user or the git hook. In both cases it is doing "echo "" > fifo_file" which should stop processes. - Then there is a process on the other end of fifo_file reading from fifo_file and actually stopping things. That second process is definitely not influenced by the "context" in which bash_script.sh is executed. The only thing I see is a wrong pwd or wrong access rights, which case the script not to be able to access the right file (your fifo_file).

Comment: You understand it right. Only the difference is that you should go further and say that the same `bash_script.sh` will also [after stopping processes] deploy new code and start processes again. And here comes weird bug that processes are not stopped. Which does not make sense to me (otherwise i wouldn't ask about this thing here)

Comment: Your bash_script.sh is doing multiple things but already the first step (stopping processes via fifo) seems to fail, so let's concentrate on that for now. - The question is: are you *sure* that your hook is accessing the right fifo file and that it has correct permissions to be able to write at it? What is the output of the above mentioned `id;pwd;ls -ld $fifo`? (both in the interactive case and in the hook case.) Only with those information it makes sense to analyze any further.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, but first, I'll give you tips to debug your problem:

- Look at your process hierarchy to know if there are process that shouldn't be there. `ps faux`
- If a process is left hanging on something, and you don't know what, you can `strace -p <PID>` to look at the system call that is blocking the process
- If this is about a file descriptor (blocking on a read or write call), then you can look at the file descriptors for that process using `lsof -p <PID>`
- Now, if you want to look at what other processes are using this file descriptor, you can look at the number on the `NODE` column and run: `lsof | grep <NODE>`

The problem I had was that the standard output and standard error from the hook script were trapped by git in a pipe to forward them to the remote host (the host that did a git push). Also, my script restarted the postgresql daemon. As a consequence, postgresql inherited the standard output and standard error from git. That is, the pipe that forwards everything back to the remote hit host.

One solution is to close stdout and stderr if you spawn services, by doing for example:

```
service postgresql restart >&- 2>&- <&-
```

But, you won't get any error message. The other and more generic solution I fould was to put the following code in my post-update hook:

```
# Creates a temp file
t="$(tempfile)" || exit
trap "rm -f -- '$t'" EXIT

# Run the script
# You need to run the script in background, and to redirect its standard and
# error output to $t
bash path/to/script.bash >"$t" 2>&1 </dev/null &

# use tail -f to follow the output of the script, and --pid to exit when the
# previous script exits ($! is the pid of the script). This might not be very
# portable though
tail -n 0 --pid $! -f "$t"

# Clean up temp file
# if a process is still attached to it, the inode won't be cleared until the
# process close the file or dies. In our case, we don't care much.
rm -f -- "$t"
trap - EXIT
```